# In Karaf, is there any way to control the order in which kar files load? Regarding cross-kar file dependencies

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

It appears in karaf, that if kar file A has a feature that depends on a feature in  kar file B, and kar file A loads before B, the install of the features in kar file A will fail, saying there is an unresolved dependency.

bundle start-levels don't seem to make a difference.

Is there any way of controlling which kar file loads first?   Or a way to resolve cross-kar dependencies?  Or even a way to make karaf not try to install any bundles/features until **all** the kar files are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible right now since the KAR deployer thinks of a KAR file to be complete. If you need such dependencies I recomend using plain features.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you this answers your question. But the order of bundle loading can be controlled in Apache Karaf using bundle-start level tag.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<features name="cxl_esb_features">
<feature name="cxl_camel_routes">
  <feature>camel-jms</feature> 
  <bundle start-level="81">mvn:org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections/3.2.1</bundle> 
  <bundle start-level="82">mvn:org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang/2.6.0</bundle> 
 </feature>
</features>
```